# Failed to download kernel source

Tags: linux

Failed to download linux kernel source. What is wrong?

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/pkgs# apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'linux' as source package instead of 'linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic'
NOTICE: 'linux' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/ubuntu-trusty.git
Need to get 125 MB of source archives.
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux 3.13.0-40.69 (dsc)
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux 3.13.0-40.69 (tar) [116 MB]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux 3.13.0-40.69 (diff)
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Fetched 116 MB in 46s (2,494 kB/s)                                             
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux_3.13.0-40.69.dsc  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux_3.13.0-40.69.diff.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch some archives.
```

I am using standard Ubuntu 14.04

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/pkgs# more /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS \n \l
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that *NOTICE: 'linux' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:*
`http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/ubuntu-trusty.git` is fairly straightforward. If you already have git installed use

```
git clone http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/ubuntu-trusty.git
```

Otherwise, install `git` first

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Comment: Thanks for tips. I tried the command `git clone http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/ubuntu-trusty.git` and it took a hour and still not finished.  Network monitoring showed that it downloaded a lot of files (over 100MB) in the beginning, but it stopped any nework activity and CPU is around 68%. I had to terminate it after 1 hour.  Wonder if this is expected.

Comment: You can restart it as long as you don't delete anything. And yes, the ubuntu kernel source is fairly large.